# Edit N templates at once via command line?

Tags: templates, replace, django-templates

I have templates which contain this block:

```
{% extends 'core/master.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% block text %}
        {{ content }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

There are roughly 50 html templates.

This block is not needed and I would like to remove it.

Unfortunately the whitespace around it varies (sometimes more whitespace, sometimes less...)

How to edit N html templates at once?

I would like to do this on the command line.

Comment: Is there something else inside the block except whitespaces or it is the same in all `html` templates?

Comment: @DimitriosStrantsalis No there is only whitespace. If there is something the replacement should not happen.

Comment: Then if I get it right, that is a matter of the editor. What editor are you using for your project?

Comment: @DimitriosStrantsalis I would like to do this on the command line.

Comment: I am almost sure this can be done very easily using Atom. If you want to do this on the command line I suggest you change the tags of your question so that it can get attention from people that can help!

Comment: What os r u using?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I use Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: does the answer I provided solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking to perform the search and replace of the text ( with minor whitespace variation ) then consider using a command line perl one-liner such as that discussed in [This BLOG](https://blog.josephscott.org/2005/08/18/perl-oneliner-recursive-search-and-replace/) or better yet at [This page](http://ask.xmodulo.com/search-and-replace-multi-line-string.html). 
I am using a mac however this should work similarly on other *nix systems.
I originally looked at [#1030787](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1030787)   however this proposed solution did not seem to work with the modifications to handle slurping files

A simple example of a multi-line replacement follows:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs perl -i -0pe  's/peter\s+is\s+good//mg'
```

The slightly messy part is constructing the correct regex. I've run a couple of tests by creating some example files matching your spec against the following and it looks to work as expected.

```
find . -name '*.html' | xargs perl -i -0pe  's|\{\%\s+extends\s+.core/master.html.\s+\%\}\s+\{\%\s+block\s+content\s+\%\}\s+\{\%\s+block\s+text\s+\%\}\s+\{\{\s+content\s+\}\}\s+\{\%\s+endblock\s+\%\}\s+\{\%\s+endblock\s+\%\}||xosmg'
```

Note that the regex includes a number of one-or-more-space \s+ matches and you also need to escape special characters '{', '}' and '%'

Initial testing suggests that this will work for your example.

Comment: I have not used perl since ages. But yes, this works. Thank you!